# Multiple bus headphone switch

Tags: mixer, headphones

I'm looking for a device with two stereo inputs and two stereo outputs which will allow me to switch between the two inputs independently on the outputs (I'm not sure what the correct term for this would be, two input/output buses?)

I can find plenty of devices where you can select which input(s) and output(s) to use, but can't find anything where I could, for example, send:

```
input A -> output A & input A -> output B
input A -> output A & input B -> output B
input B -> output A & input B -> output B
input B -> output A & input A -> output B
```

I think a matrix mixer would kind of do the job, but these all seem to have dials rather than switches to change quickly between inputs/outputs quickly,

Background of what I'm trying to do: My friend and I are DJing without using speakers due to neighbors/housemates, I want to send the master output and headphone output of my mixer into the the separate inputs of this device, then plug two sets of headphones into the separate outputs. That way we can both choose if we're hearing the headphone or master output and quickly switch between the two. Then I can listen to the master output of the mixer while my friend is cuing/beat-matching the next track and vice versa.

I think I could bodge something together using splitters on the master and headphone outputs of my mixer and two separate headphone switches, but I was wondering if there is a device which would do it.

Comment: I'd call it a matrix switch, but I wouldn't know where to look for one. A quick google, even on studio supplies sites brings up too much noise to get a clear result.

Comment: Yeah I'd tried googling for a matrix switch, get lots of results for the character Switch from the Matrix!